# Where does the text: symbol come from when rendering form input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Sorry for such a beginner question, but I had some trouble while going through the RoR [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). In the part where it says:

```
def create
  render text: params[:post].inspect
end
```

Where does this `text:` symbol come from and why does the function fail when I change it? First I thought it was the same name as the field name on the form, but after changing the field name, this method still worked. Thanks for any clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://breakthebit.org/post/8453341914/ruby-1-9-and-the-new-hash-syntax

it's newer syntax for hashes so you are passing the function render
a hash { :text => (valueof params[:post].inspect) } 
and render function knows hot to handle that parameter.
If you change :text so something unknown to the render function it will fail.

this is a link to show you what render understands and can do:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Answer (score 0):

```
render text: params[:post].inspect
```

is the shorter way of doing

```
render :text => params[:post].inspect
```

Introduced in ruby 1.9 .

If you want to support ruby, 1.8, use hash rocket `:text => params[:post].inspect )` instead